# What do I use preference or sqlite database for my application settings screen

Tags: android, preferences

Please excuse me if this is a very novice question, but I am little confused. I have a settings screen in my application, where there are check box or radio button option and spinner option. user has to select one and my application will be updated with the saved settings option. Now I believe I can do the same with sqlite database but looks like preferences is used for such kind of scenarios only. How good it will be to use preferences and not sqlite database. I am not sure which way I should head.

Please someone explain.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` is good for non-structured data. It's quite easy to use; with `SQLiteDatabase` you would end up writing quite a bit of code while never taking advantage of the core competencies of sqlite3, such as indexing, sorting and joins.

Comment: "non-structured data"    okay see i have some screens, some has no options given for user to choose from, user has to enter while some screen where user has to just choose from the option provided. so what do u mean by non-structured data? one is user enters and other is application give them option to choose from. you say option one to be non-structured?

Comment: "non-structured" meaning not organized into rows and columns. If you just want to remember a few pieces of data that doesn't need to be organized, then `SharedPreferences` is a good path.

Answer (score 3):

Go with SharedPreferences. It's a lightweight key/value store that's easy to use for primitive types.

A SQLite database is more useful if you have relational data, but it's more ceremony than you need for preferences. You'll need to write SQL queries to retrieve and update variables, manage your schema (e.g., upgrade the database if you decide to add new preferences), manage your database by opening and closing it with SqlDatabaseHelper, etc.

In short, a SQLite database is a lot of overhead you won't need.

Comment: yeah i have read that it is light weight key/value but can you please explain in detail pros and cons with respect to database. thanks in tons.

Comment: edited to add some of the disadvantages of using SQLite vs. preferences.

Comment: useful data thanks.. i think i can vote for only one answer but both are useful for me.. thanks anyways